# How do I get the private message list from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Hello everyone I need help.

Here is my table struct.
[image]

I need to find the latest message between the user with user id 1 and other users.

The result seems like this :
[image]

How do i use sql to get that ? Thanks you all.

Comment: Latest message for each other user? Does it matter if user 1 is receiver or sender?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh Thank for your reply. The mysql version is 5.7

Comment: @jarlh That is no matter.

Comment: @jarlh I just need to get the list of latest message of the user 1 sended or receved.

Comment: "Latest", does that mean latest created_at or latest updated_at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are defining "latest" -- `updated_at`? `created_at`?  or `id`?

Anyway, one approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where 1 in (m.receiver_id, m.sender_id) and
      m.updated_at = (select max(m2.updated_at)
                      from messages m2
                      where (m2.receiver_id, m2.sender_id) in ((m.receiver_id, m.sender_id), (m.sender_id, m.receiver_id))
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your sql can't run, so I referenced your answer and modified it. Now I can get it normally.

Comment: select * from private_message p where  1 in (p.receiver_id, p.sender_id) and
                                  p.created_at = (select max(p2.created_at) from private_message p2 where p2.receiver_id = p.receiver_id or p2.sender_id = p.sender_id)